# Как отправить с FFmpeg на ffserver

Tags: ffmpeg

Как отправить поток с FFmpeg (версия 4+) на ffserver?
На старой версии делал так:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i plughw:CARD=Camera,DEV=0  -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -s 640x480 -vcodec flv -acodec pcm_mulaw http://10.1.0.99:8090/webcam.ffm
```

И все работало. Если такую же команду скормить новой версии, то ошибка

> [NULL @ 0xa57cf0] Unable to find a suitable output format for
> 'http://10.1.0.99:8090/webcam.ffm' http://10.1.0.99:8090/webcam.ffm:
> Invalid argument

Читая интернет пришел к выводу, что нужно писать что-то подобное:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -framerate 20 -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -s 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -f mpegts http://10.1.0.99:8090/webcam.ffm
```

Но это дает ошибку:

> [tcp @ 0xd87240] Connection to tcp://10.1.0.99:8090 failed: Connection
> refused http://10.1.0.99:8090/webcam.ffm: Connection refused

Как в итоге можно стримить видео с камеры с помощью ffmpeg последней версии?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [FFmpeg на raspberry не отправляет видео на ffserver на компьютере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155172/ffmpeg-%d0%bd%d0%b0-raspberry-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ffserver-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что участник уже задавал похожий вопрос.